# why do most people use regexp with substr, instr, like.. and not use thoes functions without the regexp?

Tags: sql, oracle

what is the benefit of using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, rather then just `SUBSTR` , or `REGEXP_LIKE` rather then `LIKE` and so on.

for example:

```
SELECT lastname 
FROM address
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (phone, '415+');
```

VS:

```
SELECT lastname 
FROM address
WHERE phone LIKE '415%' ;
```

Is there a different case where the REGEXP is more beneficial? I have recently started learning this material, but so far have only learned about substr, instr, like... without the use of REGEXP, but have been seeing that most people use REGEXP instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `like` is faster and ANSI standard SQL.

In general `regexp_like()` is way more powerful and not all databases support regular expressions (much less `regexp_like()`).

By the way, your two conditions are not equivalent.  If you want the phone number to start with 415, then the regular expression is:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(phone, '^415');
```

Your version would match numbers that have a 415 anywhere in the `phone`, not just at the beginning.  The `+` doesn't do anything.

Comment: oh ok. i copied that example straight out of the Oracle Database complete reference book and it said that using that could would display all phone numbers that start with 415. i will test it later to see what happens

Comment: i just tried it and you are correct. i guess my oracle book is wrong. lol thanks

Comment: I would gloat, but I know how hard it is to write a book with code samples.